# Только немного изучал java. Как закрепить знания на практике?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Дело в том, что я занялся изучением явы и, приобретя немного знаний, хочу закрепить их на практике. Чем стоит заняться? Какого плана программы стоит делать?

Answer (score 1):

Выберите что-нибудь, какую-нибудь интересную для себя задачу, и начните делать.
Я в своё время делал апплет, который мониторит интернет-радио в локальной сети, и выдает, что они играют, какой их статус и так далее... потребовалось много чего интересного написать, в т.ч. свой простенький веб-сервер.

Просто выберите хорошую задачу. Например:
 1. Рисовалку, если любите GUI
 2. Веб-сайт, если любите интернет-технологии
 3. Простой проигрыватель мультимедиа, если такое интересно
 4. Сделайте какую-нибудь простую игру.

Comment: А ява апплеты еще используются?

Comment: Я делал это 8 лет назад :) Народу моя идея понравилась, и апплетом пользовались. Правда, потом появился сайт, и перешли на него. Больше я апплетов не писал, но опыт ведь бесценен, правда? :)

Answer (score 0):

На сайте coreservlets.com есть хорошие tutorials с практическими примерами. Я думаю, что это хороший способ поупражняться на практике.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://www.javatalks.ru/ftopic17191.php&highlight=%EF%EE%E4%EA%EB%FE%F7%E5%ED%E8%E5+%E1%E8%E1%EB%E8%EE%F2%E5%EA%E8) посмотри, в конце топика хороший список задач для начала =)

Comment: Спасибо. А что потом я могу делать?

Comment: Дальше, как написал andruxa, пишите свою программу это действительно интересно и помогает приобрести необходимые навыки ;)